# 403 error of phpmyadmin on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, http-status-code-403

I installed phpmyadmin on ubuntu 12.04 using the command "sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin". So, phpmyadmin is on the directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin. Then I created a link under /etc/www/ using the command "sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin". But when I visited phpmyadmin using browser, I got the error meesage "Forbidden.You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server."
I searched a lot on the Internet to find a solution. One solution is to add those following codes in the httpd.conf file(my httpd.conf file is empty.).

`<Directory “/usr/share/phpmyadmin/”>`

`AllowOverride None

Order allow,deny

Allow from all

</Directory>`

Howerver, it didn't work! Is there any one who can tell me where the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is really a better question for http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

First try to add

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

before

```
AllowOverride None
```

Also here is a tip:

If you created a symbolic link with a root user in example, then you might get that error because original resource is maybe somebody's else but link is owned by root. This usually happens on C-Panel hostings of course. I'm not sure it will happen under Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I deleted the link "phpmyadmin" under /var/www/ and directly moved the phpmyadmin folder to /var/www instead of creating a link file. Then I found that it works! Although I do not know why, it is good news that my phpmyadmin works well.